# SparkSQL spanning of Cassandra logical rows

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a situation where I would like to "iterate" or map over "wide-rows" and not the logical Cassandra rows (CQL rows) using SparkSQL.

Basically my data is partitioned by `timestamp` (partition key) and there is a clustering key which is the sensor ID.

For each `timestamp` I would like to perform operations, a trivial example is to do `sensor1/sensor2`.

How could I do that efficiently with SparkSQL by keeping the data locality (and I think that my data model is rather well suited for these tasks)?

I read [this post on Datastax](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/zen-art-spark-maintenance) which mentions `spanBy` and `spanByKey` in the Cassandra connector. How would this be used with SparkSQL?

Example of pseudo-code (pySpark):

```
ds = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM measurements WHERE timestamp > xxx")
# span the ds by clustering key
# filter the ds " sensor4 > yyy "
# for each wide-row do sensor4 / sensor1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible right now. The `spanBy` API is only accessible from the programmatic API. To enable it in SparkSQL, it would require extending the SparkSQL syntax to inject extra clause and it's a hard job...

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is it available in the pyspark (targetholding) connector? Do you think you could propose an alternative way with SparkSQL?

Comment: I don't think it is available with pyspark since pyspark is using dataframe underneath (the doc says **you are limited to DataFrame only operations**)

Comment: The best option is to create an JIRA and ask for extending `spanBy` feature to pySpark or/and SparkSQL.